# Not uniformly continuous properties

Tags: real-analysis

There are many properties which state that a function is uniformly continuous I want to know the properties or the rules by which we can identify a non uniformly continuous function and can we have some necessary and sufficient conditions for it?

Kindly help.

Comment: This question is, in my opinion, too broad. Uniform continuity is a natural property not only in metric spaces, but also in topological uniform spaces. These spaces can be rather different from each other, so that a characterization of uniformly continuous functions seems to be very hard. On $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$, sufficient conditions are often based on the splitting of the domain into a compact subset and another subset where the function has a precise growth, like an affine map.

Comment: That's why I usually get stuck in the problems of uniform continuity. e.g. a bounded function with bounded derivative is u.c. in given domain but if a function a unbounded or derivative is unbounded it may or may not be u.c. I want to clear this confusion about not uniformly continuous function by their properties.

Comment: I think you'll struggle to find characterisations for non-u.c. functions since the only criteria that they have is that they aren't uniformly continuous. Consider linear and non-linear differential equations, linear differential equations are very well understood and easy to work with and solve. However if you look at nonlinear differential equations then there are an infinite number and many many sub classes which are understood to varying degrees, however there is no single theory with which they are all studied.

Comment: Yes that's true but then how to deal with questions in which non u.c. functions are asked?

Comment: If it's a university course question then normally you have to show that the function doesn't fit the definition of u.c, i.e. show that given any $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, there is a point in the functional domain for which the definition doesn't hold. Do you have a specific question that you are stuck on? If so maybe add that into the above Question as an example.